# How to change items gravity in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left, navigationview

[image]

I need to position my navView items (rtl) , I searched in google and stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything except this lines in my NavigationView :

```
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
```

And it seems it's not supported below api 17 ..

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/darkerMilk"
    app:menu="@menu/xxx_drawermenu"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"/>
```

And menu Items

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="Inbox"
      android:id="@+id/nav_item_inbox"
      android:icon="@drawable/arrow"/>

<item android:title="Sent"
      android:id="@+id/nav_item_sent"
      android:icon="@drawable/arrow"/>

<item android:title="Drafts"
      android:id="@+id/nav_item_draft"
      android:icon="@drawable/arrow"/>
```

**navigationView class**

```
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView) ;


 mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
 NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
           // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

             if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
             }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_exit) {

            }


             return false;
        }

    });
```

Do you know any workaround for this !?

Comment: Have you added `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest?

Comment: Show the code where you initiated navigationView in class.

Comment: @Wizard  yes I did

Comment: Try `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection()` for lower api versions.

Answer (score 0):

On your NavigationItem tag just add

```
android:layoutDirection="locale"
```

Being like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:id="@+id/navigationView"
app:itemTextColor="@color/darkerMilk"
app:menu="@menu/xxx_drawermenu"
android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
android:layoutDirection="locale"/>
```